# How to compare the contents of two directory using bash?

Tags: bash

I have 2 directories that should contain the same files and the same directory structure.

I think that in one of these directories missing something.

Using the bash shell are there a way to compare my directories and see if in one of the tese missing files that are present in the other one?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 7):

`diff` can go through directories by itself, instead of parsing the output of `ls`, `find`, or `stat`

`diff -qr dir1 dir2 | sort`

You will receive output like the following:

`Only in dir2: file3`

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest method is using command substitution with the `diff` command:

```
diff <(cd dir1 && find | sort) <(cd dir2 && find | sort)
```

This will show differences in the file listing, if you actually want to compare if the file actually differs, then you may prefer `diff -brief -rb dir1 dir2`